# Почему ошибка в формате svg?

Tags: java, android

Любое изображение какое я не скачаю из интернета для теста в формате svg при загрузке в приложение обводит красным... Почему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибки в нём есть, красными черточками обозначены строки с ошибками.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите работать с svg, рекомендую преобразовать его в VectorDrawable, а дальше возможности неограниченные. Только попробуйте вначале на простых рисунках, со временем поймете где, происходят сложности в конвертации.

Закидывайте сюда  [svg -> android](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/)

С каждым днем аналогичных ресурсов всё больше и больше, чувствую скоро даже этого не придется делать.

Comment: В студии есть плагин который который конвертирует прям на месте... А такой вопрос, с этим форматом можно так же работать как и с SVG? он тоже без потери качества делает resize?

Comment: официальный плагин? можно ссылочку

Comment: Я не знаю официальный ли он, но когда я загрузил svg студия сама предложила поставить... вот ссылка с гита https://github.com/misakuo/svgtoandroid.git     а вообще он называется SVG2VectorDrawable

Comment: Спасибо я понял. Насчет первого коммента, я даже не знаю как правильно ответить. 

SVG - это лишь формат распространенный в сети, который хранит наш рисуночек в нужном виде. А вот VectorDrawable это класс, я бы сказал основной класс на данный момент работающий с векторной графикой в android вот и всё. Проще - API векторной графики.

Answer (score 0):

**file->settings->plugins** "svgviewer" поставь возможно просто ide ни чего не знает про svg формат

[image: Нужно нажать Browse repositories...]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня не находит такого плагина svgviewer ((( может он не так называется?

Comment: там есть ссылка browser нажимаешь на нее и далее ищешь

Comment: ну да я знаю, но мне ничего не показывает, можешь скрин кинуть ? как это выглядит у тебя?

Comment: Очень странно... У меня вот так это выглядит https://dropmefiles.com/LZy4c там скриншот